# maping over data with bind_cols in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am tyring to apply a series of functions over some data and bind the results together.

What I have currently is the following:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tsfeatures)

data(FANG)

FANG_returns <- FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = adjusted, 
               mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
               period     = "daily", 
               type       = "arithmetic")

FANG_returns
```

This does not work.

```
FANG_returns %>%
  nest(symbol) %>%
  summarise(Statistics = map(data, ~ data.frame(bind_cols(
    tsfeatures(.x$,
               c("acf_features","entropy","lumpiness",
                 "flat_spots","crossing_points"))))))
```

Each of the functions in the `tsfeatures` create more than one column, so essentially I am trying to run these calculations and then bind all the columns together. My problem is with the `.x$` part and R not being able to understand what I want it to do.

I took the code from:

```
library(tsfeatures)
library(dplyr)

yahoo <- yahoo_data()

bind_cols(
  tsfeatures(yahoo,
             c("acf_features","entropy","lumpiness",
               "flat_spots","crossing_points")),
  tsfeatures(yahoo,"stl_features", s.window='periodic', robust=TRUE),
  tsfeatures(yahoo, "max_kl_shift", width=48)) # This could take a few minutes to run....
```

and now I am trying to adapt it to work in my model.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think this solved my issue:

```
  summarise(Statistics = map(data, ~ bind_cols(
    tsfeatures(.x$value,
               c("acf_features","entropy","lumpiness",
                 "flat_spots","crossing_points")))))
```

Comment: 2nd thing `browser()` is our friend when you get stuck try `FANG_returns %>%
 nest(-symbol) %>% mutate(Statistics = map(data, ~browser()))` to understand what `.x` you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't know of it before. Using your method I get: `Error in unnest(Statistics) : object 'Statistics' not found` - I get this same error with my own solution (see edit)

Comment: Okay adding `tsfeatures(.x$daily.returns, 
               c("acf_features","entropy","lumpiness", "flat_spots","crossing_points")))))))` solved that issue of `not found`

Comment: Try `FANG_returns %>% nest(-symbol) %>% mutate(Statistics = map(data, ~ data.frame(bind_cols( tsfeatures(.x, c("acf_features","entropy","lumpiness", "flat_spots","crossing_points")))))) %>% unnest(Statistics)`, works fine for me.